# Hover on getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I hope someone can answer my question, it is probably easy for you but I am not very used to JavaScript.

So I made a menu using this code:

```
function tabSwitch(new_tab, new_content) {  

    document.getElementById('content_1').style.display = 'none';  
    document.getElementById('content_2').style.display = 'none';  
    document.getElementById('content_3').style.display = 'none';          
    document.getElementById(new_content).style.display = 'block';     

    document.getElementById('tab_1').className = '';  
    document.getElementById('tab_2').className = '';  
    document.getElementById('tab_3').className = '';          
    document.getElementById(new_tab).className = 'active';        

}
```

When clicking on the area of `tab_1` the `content_1` is displayed and so on. But I would like to get the content displayed when the mouse hovers over the area of the different tabs. 
Could you please help me, I looked up the web but I could not find anything, maybe because I have actually no idea of JavaScript.

So, thanks for your time and help.

**EDIT:**

Is this where the TabSwitch is called... I hope so

```
<ul class="tabs">  
    <li><a href="javascript:tabSwitch('tab_1', 'content_1');" id="tab_1" class="active"><img src="img/flash.png" /></a></li>  
    <li><a href="javascript:tabSwitch('tab_2', 'content_2');" id="tab_2"><img src="img/brush.png" /></a></li>  
    <li><a href="javascript:tabSwitch('tab_3', 'content_3');" id="tab_3"><img src="img/wheel.png" /></a></li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: jQuery makes this simpler

Comment: Can you show the code where `tabSwitch` is being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go for the [onmouseover](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp) event, as it is supported for a and li tags as well, and additionally check out the onmouseout (very similar) to be aware of both.

With this, the li tags for the menu elements would look like:

```
<li onmouseover="tabSwitch('tab_1', 'content_1');"><a href="#" id="tab_1" class="active"><img src="img/flash.png" /></a></li>
<li onmouseover="tabSwitch('tab_2', 'content_2');"><a href="#" id="tab_2"><img src="img/brush.png" /></a></li>
```

Onmouseover will fire, when you hover over the element. I think you get the idea from here.

Comment: I really never use it, I just copied because OP had it in the question. I was trying to edit as little as possible to focus on the answer for he question.

Comment: He had a `javascript:`-link (in the href-attribute), while you have an inline handler code. Remove it.